# Testing async function with mocha always ends with .catch()

Tags: asynchronous, mocha.js

I am trying to test a generic fetch function, which based on the server response calls a respective callback.
So, the function looks somewhat like this:

```
const myFetch = (url, body, onSuccess, onError) => {
  let status = 0;
  fetch(url, header(body))
  .then(response => {
    status = response.status;
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(jData => {
    switch (status) {
      case 200:
      case 201:
        onSuccess(jData, 'success');
        break;
      default:
        onError([], 'error');
        break;
    }
  })
  .catch(() => {
    onError([], 'error');
  });
};
```

So in my mocha test I am trying to assert the message that is delivered either by onSuccess() or on onError() callback:

```
it('should perform fetch', function (done) {
    this.timeout(5000);
    const url = 'http://httpstat.us/201';

    const onSuccess = (res, mes) => {
      expect(mes).eq('success');
      done();
    };

    const onError = (err, mes) => {
      expect(mes).eq('error');
      done();
    };

    Utils.myFetch(url, null, onSuccess, onError);
  });
```

However, although I know that 201 is returned, I seem to always get into `.catch()` part of the fetch, so I never actually get into `onSuccess` callback.

Is there anything I am doing wrong? Will be greatful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, it was not really a mocha problem: the reason is `return response.json();` in the first promise, while the used service returns the content of type plain text.